# How to nest objects when building JSON with JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to encode this string for a `POST` request. Can anyone tell me how I can encode

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "Files.GetSources", "params":{"media":"music"}, "id": 1}
```

So far I have

```
JSONOjbect obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("jsonrpc", "2.0");
obj.put("method", "Files.GetSources");
```

But I'm not sure how to put in the rest - can anyone help?

Comment: You're going to have to be _a lot_ more specific if you expect any useful replies.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you're asking how you'd put the nested `params` object in there, you'd probably do:

```
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
params.put("media", "music");

obj.put("params", params);
```

---

To use an array (per your comments below), you'd do something like this:

```
JSONArray properties = new JSONArray();
properties.put("resume");
properties.put("genre");
properties.put("studio");
...

JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
params.put("properties", properties);

obj.put("params", params);
```

Comment: thanks! That worked! Sorry for being vague, could you multiple nested? For example .. for one like this..

{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "VideoLibrary.GetMovies", "params": {"properties": ["resume", "genre", "studio", "tagline", "runtime", "fanart", "thumbnail", "file", "plot", "plotoutline", "year", "lastplayed", "rating"]}, "id": 1}

Comment: Yes, you can nest things as far as you like (using the same principle from this answer). For your `properties`, you'd use a [`JSONArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) instead of `JSONObject`.

Comment: @RethinavelPillai - It's the OP's original, top-level object that he's trying to add nested items to.

Answer (score 3):

```
JSONOjbect obj = new JSONObject().put("jsonrpc", "2.0")
    .put("method", "Files.GetSources").put("id", 1)
    .put("params", new JSONObject().put("media", "music"));
```

Chaining .put() like this is possible because put() returns the object it was called on - for this exact purpose.

Comment: There are missing parenthesis: `JSONOjbect obj = new JSONObject().put("jsonrpc", "2.0")
    .put("method", "Files.GetSources").put("id", 1)
    .put("params", new JSONObject().put("media", "music"));`

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices.  You can create another object that holds `"media":"music"` and then put that in the original `JSONObject` or you can just pass this whole string into the `JSONObject` constructor and have it parse it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you do have the string before hand, you can simply do

```
JSONObject object = JSONObject.getJSONObject("{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"Files.GetSources\", \"params\":{\"media\":\"music\"}, \"id\": 1}");
```