# Android Volley POST - JSON Encoding in body

Tags: java, android, http, android-volley

I'm using Volley Android for POST some data to a Restful Api endpoint, using postman it works great body data in `raw` and `application/json` e.g:

```
{
    "operation": "someaction",
    "key": "pk_test_fssdfsdfjkhkjsdhf84334",
    "token": "tk_test_432332sdxxaJJJJHHHshhsas",
    "ssids":[[{
        "mac":"34:15:13:d4:59:f1" //<--this is important here, it's mac addr
            }]] //<-- yup, with double double [[ ... ]]
}
```

It works using POSTMAN and returns
[image]

The issue starts when I use volley in the code below:

```
public void getBleeCardData(Response.Listener<String> response, final String ssidsdata, final ProgressDialog pd)throws JSONException {

    String url = "https://www......com/api/something.do";

    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
               jsonBody.put("operation", "something");
               jsonBody.put("key", "pk_try_oqiwFHFKjkj4XMrh");
               jsonBody.put("token", "tk_tkn_erwweelWgH4olfk2");
               jsonBody.put("ssids", ssidsdata.toLowerCase()); 

    final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("Response", response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("ERROR", "error => " + error.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            try {
                return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT))); }
```

I need help with the encoding, using Volley the data sent like:

{"operation":"dataMachines","key":"pk_test_6pRNAHGGoqiwFHFKjkj4XMrh","token":"tk_test_ZQokik736473jklWgH4olfk2","ssids":"[[{\"mac\":\"34:15:13:d4:59:f1\"}]]"}

Why is sending this node like `"ssids":"[[{\"mac\":\"34:15:13:d4:59:f1\"}]]"}`like this?, What about the `"\"`, some special encoding to remove it?

Is possible change the encoding to prevent those `"\"`?

Comment: no encoding will be used unless its specified in the header of the POST request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject obmacAdd=new JSONObject();
JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
obmacAdd.put("mac","34:15:13:d4:59:f1");
array.put(obmacAdd.toString());
```

now

```
jsonBody.put("ssids", array.toString());
```

Comment: your solution works good, I was parsing to String and it converts to String encoding, finally I passed it using **JSONArray** and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Create a JsonObjectRequest

```
JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
           jsonBody.put("operation", "something");
           jsonBody.put("key", "pk_try_oqiwFHFKjkj4XMrh");
           jsonBody.put("token", "tk_tkn_erwweelWgH4olfk2");
           jsonBody.put("ssids", ssidsdata.toLowerCase()); 

JsonObjectRequest jobReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonBody,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                //Log.d("Responses", jsonObject.toString());
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                //Log.e("responses", volleyError.toString());
            }
        });
```

if you are sending JSONArray then instead of JsonObjectRequest  use JsonArrayRequest

Comment: you answer looks good, maybe in optimisation time I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the android code,the below expects a string,while you are parsing an object:

```
 jsonBody.put("ssids", ssidsdata.toLowerCase());
```

You could make the ssid seperately then add it in the json body like this:

```
JSONObject ssid= new JSONObject();
ssid.put("mac":"34:15:13:d4:59:f1");
ssid.put("key2","Value2");
```

The add the ssid object into your Json object to send:

```
    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    jsonBody.put("operation", "something");
     jsonBody.put("key", "pk_try_oqiwFHFKjkj4XMrh");
   jsonBody.put("token", "tk_tkn_erwweelWgH4olfk2");
  jsonBody.put("ssids", ssid);
```

As well explaned here: [Pass an object containing key value pairs, as a value to a hashmap in Java/Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9231157/4183833)